# Geometry confusion with incident E field

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, geometric-optics

My geometry is very rusty and I'm having trouble understanding why for the incident E field the X component is multiplied by cos and the -Z component is multiplied by sin instead of the other way around. Would someone please explain this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's zoom in to your diagram a bit and draw in some extra angles:

[image]

This should make it obvious why $E_x = E \cos\theta$ and $E_z = E\sin\theta$.